# Laravel save model into sqlserver

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, save, refresh

Morning,

I notice something strange into Laravel.
After creating new data using model, i do save and refresh model.
But when i try to see new record into my database is not exist.
Although this new data is exit into current model.

```
$data = DATA::create(newdatafield);
$data->save();
$data->refresh();

$linkdata = DATA::all();

dd($data); //new data exist into this model 
dd($linkdata);  // new data not exist into this model
```

How is it possible ? and can i fix it ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: `create()` saves a new model and returns the instance, so there is no need for the `save` method. I also am unsure what you're trying to accomplish by using the `refresh()`.

Comment: Do you have new records in database table after saving your model? If you do, then you may have scope on your model that filter you results (and so `::all()` returns nothing). If you don't, then you have something that prevents save action (it could be an observer).

Comment: @Bennet I know no need to save and refresh data after create but it's just because i can't understand why new data is created into my model and not created into my database...

Comment: @Petr Thks for your reply, my issue that data not save into my database after create. 
I notice that some data are save into my database but not all.
There is also no error message.

Comment: Well, that's weird... It could be model observer. Does DATA have a `boot` method? Could you show it?

Comment: @Petr No, DATA has not boot method.

Comment: Does your model have `$fillable` property in a class definition?

Comment: @Petr, Thks to help me. Yes my class have $fillable property. I notice also that after deleting last record everything it's ok but after creating new one its same thing.

Comment: Could you show exact code part where you create your DATA? And whole DATA class definition?